# Firebase Remote Config - check if value exists

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I want to implement kind of a proxy for some boolean values in my app. The logic would be as follows:

1. I receive a set of values from my back-end
2. I have some of these values set in Firebase as well
3. When using a value in the app, I first check if it exists in Firebase

   3.1. If it exists, take the Firebase value

   3.2. If it does not exist, take the backend value

The question is - how can I check if the value exists in Firebase Remote Config?

Comment: Can I ask what is the use case for doing so? What feature are you trying to power through this?

Comment: Or are you building this as a backup if someone messes up in Remote Config default values?

Comment: The other way around - if someone messes something in the back-end, I want to be able to quickly override the value the users get in their app (as I can not edit the back-end and it usually takes lota of time to get something to change in it)

Comment: What happens if you do a getString() on a key which is neither defined in the defaults.xml or in the remote config console?

Comment: You will get "", which is the solution I posted below :D

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I was more interested in the use case :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It'd be so cool if Remote Config could replace all your literals while you are writing code. So if you write String var_foo="bar", it could show a code hint, saying convert var_foo to remote config key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the solution:

Firebase Remote Config fetches ALL values as `Strings` and only then maps them to other types in convenience methods such as `getBoolean()`, `getLong()` etc.

Therefore, a boolean config value existence can be checked as follows:

```
String value = firebaseRemoteConfig.getString("someKey");

if(value.equals("true")){
    //The value exists and the value is true
} else if(value.equals("false")) {
    //The value exists and the value is false
} else if(value.equals("")) {
    //The value is not set in Firebase
}
```

Same goes for other types, i.e. a `long` value set to 64 on firebase will be returned from `getString()` as `"64"`.

Comment: Note that this is only valid if no default values are defined via `setDefaultsAsync()`. When you did define a default, `getString()` will return the default value.

Answer (score 12):

I found another way, maybe useful for someone else landing here:

```
val rawValue = remoteConfig.getValue(key)
val exists = rawValue.source == FirebaseRemoteConfig.VALUE_SOURCE_REMOTE
```

In this case `exists` will be true only if the value is returned from remote (and and has not been set as default or static provided value). The accepted answer is error prone as does not consider the case where the empty String is a valid String returned from remote

Here the docs for [FirebaseRemoteConfigValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfigValue)

Comment: This is the correct answer. For C#: bool exists = rawValue.source == ValueSource.RemoteValue; Documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase/remote-config#namespace_firebase_1_1_remote_config_1a2f4f400ab2b2d9f09a147439cd0c5ca2

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Remote Config (FRC), actually provides 3 constants to know from where is the value retrieved with `getValue(forKey)` ([documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig#VALUE_SOURCE_STATIC))

- VALUE_SOURCE_DEFAULT --> value from default set by user
- VALUE_SOURCE_REMOTE --> value from remote server
- VALUE_SOURCE_STATIC --> value returned is default (FRC don't have the key)

Knowing this, you can do a "wrapper" like this:

```
class FirebaseRemoteConfigManager {
.....

    override fun getBoolean(forKey: String): Boolean? = getRawValue(forKey)?.asBoolean()

    override fun getString(forKey: String): String? = getRawValue(forKey)?.asString()

    override fun getDouble(forKey: String): Double? = getRawValue(forKey)?.asDouble()

    override fun getLong(forKey: String): Long? = getRawValue(forKey)?.asLong()

    private fun getRawValue(forKey: String): FirebaseRemoteConfigValue? {
        val rawValue = remoteConfig.getValue(forKey)
        return if (rawValue.source == FirebaseRemoteConfig.VALUE_SOURCE_STATIC) null else rawValue
    }
...
}
```

If you get a `null`, you know the key don't exist in FRC.
Take care of using default values as "not exist", because maybe in your FRC you want to set this value, and you will have a false positive

Answer (score 0):

Remote Config already does this, as described in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android).  You're obliged to provide [default values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#set-in-appdefault-parameter-values) for parameters that haven't been defined in the console.  They work exactly as you describe, without having to do any extra work.  These defaults will be used until you perform a [fetch](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-android#fetch-andactivate-values-from-the-service-as-needed).  If the value is defined in the console, then it will be used instead of the default.

Comment: The problem is, the values would be dynamic. I want to be able to add a firebase proxy value without redeploying the app. Also, there is no obligation to define defaults from what I have seen. It just returns the default value for that data type (false, "" or 0)

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you're trying to do.  What's a "firebase proxy value"?

Comment: These firebase values are supposed to be master values. So if there is one in firebase, use that. If not, use the one retrieved from the backend. And I want to be able to iterate all back-end values, check if there is an override in firebase and use that if so.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to know if a parameter has a value in the console unless you place a special value there that indicates to the app not to use it.